# My screen freezes after changing the text

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the addChangeTextListener but my screen freezes when I click on a key.
Here is the code:

```
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);


    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    { 
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        { 
            if (email.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+") 
                    && s.length() > 0)
                error.setText("valid email");
            else
               email.setText("invalid email");              
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) 
        {   
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) 
        {                   
        } 
    });
```

Comment: A guess, but would calling setText call afterTextChanged causing an infinite loop?

Comment: The setText method is used on another EditText insntance(error) ow looks like I did a mistake... email.setText("invalid email");

Comment: `email.setText("invalid email");` Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Lol, based on the answers, looks like I should have answered.

Comment: lol I didn't noticed!! it's working now. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
email.setText("invalid email");
```

The above line should be:

```
error.setText("invalid email");
```

By using `setText()`, you are triggering `afterTextChanged()` again.

Answer (score 1):

In your else statement, you have a typo.  You want to call setText on error, not email.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your text within your change listener is causing an infinite loop, because it will call the change listener again.

From the android documentation for `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged()`:

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text
>   has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from
>   this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite
>   loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called
>   again recursively. (You are not told where the change took place
>   because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other
>   changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need to know here, you
>   can use setSpan(Object, int, int, int) in onTextChanged(CharSequence,
>   int, int, int) to mark your place and then look up from here where the
>   span ended up.

Make sure you didn't mean to call `error.setText()` instead of `email.setText()`.